# Javascript not working on GoDaddy hosting

Tags: javascript, linux, server

Here is my code.

```
var cSharpButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("csharpbutton");
var jSButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("jsbutton");
var cSharp = document.getElementsByClassName("csharp");
var jS = document.getElementsByClassName("js");

function switchToCSharp() 
{
    for (i = 0; i < cSharpButtons.length; i++) //change button colors
    { 
        cSharpButtons[i].style.backgroundColor = "#00AEEF";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < jSButtons.length; i++) 
    { 
        jSButtons[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cSharp.length; i++) //change code
    { 
        cSharp[i].style.display = "inline";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < jS.length; i++) 
    { 
        jS[i].style.display = "none";
    }

}

function switchToJS() 
{
    for (i = 0; i < jSButtons.length; i++) //change button colors
    { 
        jSButtons[i].style.backgroundColor = "#00AEEF";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < cSharpButtons.length; i++) 
    { 
        cSharpButtons[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < cSharp.length; i++) //change code
    { 
        cSharp[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < jS.length; i++) 
    { 
        jS[i].style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

GoDaddy said the permission were fine. Works like a charm on my desktop, they said something must be wrong with my code. They said it could be an outdated way of coding it.

nothing happens when you press a button, to try it for yourself visit http://spacehelmetstudios.com/tutorials/unity2d/directionalgravity2d/directionalgravity2d.html and try to change it from C# to JS.

I'm not going to lie, I don't know very much about the server side of things.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You could use the developer console of your browser to get a better idea of the error. (Ctrl + Shift + i in Chrome, f12 in IE etc). https://i.thomas.gg/qlP5yml.png

Comment: http://spacehelmetstudios.com/js/switchLanguage.js returns ERROR 404

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer, but in developers console I don't see any JS file downloaded and i get a console error saying that your functions are not defined. Maybe you forgot to add your JS files in your `<head>` tag?

Comment: Thanks, just double checked, it's there <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/switchLanguage.js"></script>

Comment: Wonder why it wouldn't find it.

Comment: You're a genius! It was ther but the L in language was capitalized but it's reference wasn't.

Comment: I feel embarrassed, I will do more troubleshooting next time but thanks man I was starting to get flustered.

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us, no matter how experience we have